# Hadoop records being processed multiple times when * is specified in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

If I specify `*` in my input hdfs path as `/user/analytics/batch_jobs/2016-06-09/*/BATCH*/`, the number of records being processed by Mapper job is twice.

However if I copy `/user/analytics/batch_jobs/2016-06-09/*/BATCH*/*` to /user/tmp/ in hdfs, the behaviour is normal and each record is processed only once.

hadoop fs -cat `/user/analytics/batch_jobs/2016-06-09/*/BATCH*/* | wc -l`
and `hadoop fs -cat /user/tmp/test.dat | wc -l` shows equal number of records.

What is the problem in using * in my hdfs input path?

Comment: What is the output of the follow command: hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/analytics/batch_jobs/2016-06-09/*/BATCH*/. Are the files duplicated ?

Comment: The files are not duplicate..